# VBA to Select variable rows across columns

Tags: vba, excel

current code is

```
lngLastRowDPWK = ActiveSheet.Cells(Activesheet.Rows.Count,"DX".End(xlUP).Row+3

Range("DP" & lngLastRowDPWK:"DV" & lngLastRowDPWK +2).select
```

I'm wanting it to highlight a few rows of in columns DP-DV but the row number is a variable.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub test()
    'You were missing a ")"
    lngLastRowDPWK = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "DX").End(xlUp).Row + 3
    'You weren't creating the string correctly
    Range("DP" & lngLastRowDPWK & ":DV" & lngLastRowDPWK + 2).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Range("DP" & lngLastRowDPWK & ":" & "DV" & lngLastRowDPWK +2).select

Comment: Thank you I found that variation as well at the same time. I will use yours in my code though thanks for the help

Comment: @user3066795 - Why are you selecting the data? FYI it's best to [avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)